# How to plot a triangular function and other step functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

As the title indicates, I want to know how to plot a triangular function in Matlab. e.g.

```
f(x) = 1-|x| for |x| < 1 and f(x) = 0 otherwise
```

As well as the functions:

```
Af(x) = A for x >= 0 and Af(x) = 0 for x < 0; -f(x) = -1 for x >= 0 and -f(x) = 0 for x < 0
```

Comment: I don't see anything special about these functions, plot like every other function. Where are you stuck? Please add your code to the question.

Comment: All I can try is this:

x=-50:50; y=[zeros(1,50) ones(1,21) zeros(1,30)]; plot(x,y); axis([-55 55 -0.1 1.1])

But this gives a rectangular function, not a triangular or the other two.

Comment: This simply does not match your function definition. I don't see any `1-abs(x)` in your code, how should this work? Write a matlab-function which implements 'f(x)=1-|x| for |x|<1 and f(x)=0', test it and then try to plot it.

Comment: This is what I am asking actually @DanielR

Comment: If you don't know how to write such a simple function, you should start reading the documentation for matlab.

Comment: If it is as simple as you have emphasized, why don't you just tell me rather than keep writing comments. I wouldn't have asked had if been I know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are not using symbolic variables. For 2D plotting in matlab you need two equal size vectors, one per axis, so you need to create a x-axis vector and y-axis vector. In your example f(x) = 1- |x| for |x| < 1 you could do this:

```
x = linspace(-5,5,500); %x-axis vector from -5 to 5 with 500 points
y = zeros(1,500);  %y-axis vector initialized to 0, also 500 points like the x-axis vector
y(abs(x) < 1) = 1- abs(x(abs(x)<1)); %the points corresponding to |x|< 1 are set to |x|

figure() %new figure
plot(x,y) %plot
box off  %removing box
grid on  %adding grid
xlabel('x axis', 'FontSize', 15) %label of x axis
ylabel('y axis', 'FontSize', 15) %label of y axis
axis([x(1), x(end), -0.5, 1.5])  %axis limits
```

With that you get a plot like this one:

[image]

For the other functions you have to proceed like in this one, build the x-axis vector and the y-axis vector.

**UPDATE:** In the other example: `f(x) = A for x >= 0 and f(x) = 0 for x < 0`:

```
A = 3;
x = linspace(-5,5,500); %x-axis vector from -5 to 5 with 500 points
y = zeros(1,500);  %y-axis vector initialized to 0, also 500 points like the x-axis vector
y(x >= 0) = A; %the points corresponding to x >= 0 are set to A

figure() %new figure
plot(x,y) %plot
box off  %removing box
grid on  %adding grid
xlabel('x axis', 'FontSize', 15) %label of x axis
ylabel('y axis', 'FontSize', 15) %label of y axis
axis([x(1), x(end), -0.5, 3.5])  %axis limits
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much @pabaldonedo, it looks exactly like what I need. And how should I go on with the other two functions please?

Comment: I have updated to solve the second example, set A constant to the value you need. If it helps please upvote.

Comment: Of course it helps and thanks so much. Unfortunately I can't upvote because I have just 14 reputations, though I have chosen this as my best answer. Am not frequenting Stackoverflow like I frequent Mathstackexchange.